# Position a tooltip not relative to the "origin" [css]

Tags: html, css, hover, tooltip

I have several images which have a Tooltip on hover ( which display another image)

The thing looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjywK.jpg

Now my problem is that, everytime I hover over one image it locks the tooltip to the   image. So the tooltip is in a different position everytime I hover over a different image. my css for this looks like this:

```
.playertooltip {
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}

.playertooltip span {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    border: 5px solid white;

}

.playertooltip:hover span {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    border: 5px solid white;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Well, I want to find a fixed position for EVERY tooltip so that, when I hover over different images the tooltip appears in the same place.

Thanks for the help :)

For clarifycation:
http://jsfiddle.net/auNVb/

Comment: A jsfiddle or something would be helpful. It's not really clear what your CSS selectors are referencing in the image mockup. I'd like to see HTML too.

Comment: updated. The Text "Tooltip Content" is what I want to position in only 1 place. Not under every element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hovered **position** needs to be changed to **fixed**, add a **left/right** position of 50% and a variable **top** position like the following:

```
.playertooltip {
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}

.playertooltip span {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    border: 5px solid white;

}

.playertooltip:hover span {
    display: block;
    position:fixed; /* Changed from absolute */
    border: 5px solid white;
    z-index: 99;
    left: 50%; /* Move it to the "half" of the page */
    top: 20%; /* Move it to the "half" of the page (from the top). 
                 You have to experiment with this, 
                     as I had variable results depending 
                         on the elements present in the page. */
}
```

Comment: Um, THANK YOU. I don't know why i didnt figure that out before. I played with the position but it didn't work for me. Works Great now, I try to avoid the left: 50%, because it doesn't work good on scaling sites but thank you never the less!

Comment: I wrote this before you put a fiddle. Looking at the fiddle you posted **left** should be **40%** and not **50%**

Comment: @user3648229 Welcome :) The thing is that you should also add position "coordinates" for it to work

Comment: yeah I tried, setting it to 0 is good enough though. Thank you very much everything is working now like intended.